# Conditional permission declarations

Tags: android

I'm building an application for Android that is partitioned around SDK version `29`. For compatibility reasons, the app must implement a feature differently on SDK versions `< 29` and `>= 29`. These two versions require a different set of permissions. Currently, the application automatically switches the feature depending on the active SDK version. My application is getting rejected by the Play Store because all permissions are declared for both app versions. The `>= 29` version for example does not need as many (sensitive) permissions as the `< 29` version but is rejected for not actively using these permissions.

I've read about [manifest merging](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge), but I'm not sure if it can achieve what I'd like (conditional permission declaration).

I would like to maintain only *one* apk that handles both app versions. Is it possible to declare conditional manifest permissions, something like:

```
<if minSdkVersion="29">
    <!-- Arbitrary permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
</if>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in `maxSdkVersion`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" 
android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
```